# How do I cancel a promise inside the "done" callback?

Tags: jquery, promise, jquery-deferred, cancellation

I have the following scenario...

```
$.when(
    $.getScript('script.js')
).done(function () {
    if ( scriptIsAlreadyLoaded ) {
        // I want to cancel this promise.
        // I no longer want script.js because
        // it has already been loaded in another
        // instance.
    }

    // I dont' want this to run if the above
    // condition is true.
    doStuff();
});
```

I understand that doing this inside `done()` doesn't make much sense since, by definition, it's too late to cancel the promise.

So what would be the best approach here?

> **NOTE:** This snippet could be executed multiple times. This is why I want to avoid the script from being loaded more than once.

Comment: Eh... inside the done it is already... done. I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish at all. Just keep a boolean flag and surround the `$.when` with an `if`.

Comment: Using $.getScript automatically parses the script, so even if you canceled it, it would already be loaded, so this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Also, in addition to what @adeneo said browsers cache scripts (unless your server sends incorrect cache headers), so it won't be making the request the second time anyway.

Comment: Also, it seems it could be just done like -> http://jsfiddle.net/y76Be/

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, I get that it doesn't make sense in the `done()` function (I admitted to that in the post). I was hoping I could get a suggestion for an alternative that actually does make sense.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, the script in question has cache-blocker (timestamp appended to the URL as a parameter; nothing I can do about it).

Comment: @adeneo, I went with your approach: good ol' fashion success callback. I was trying to get fancy with deferred objects. Anyways, if you flesh out your comment into a proper answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It makes no sense to cancel a promise inside the `.done()` handler.  When the `.done()` handler is called the operation is already complete (it sounds like maybe you already know that).  So, when your `.done()` handler is called, the load of your script has already completed.  There is nothing left to cancel.

If you just want to prevent your own code from trying to load the script multiple times, then you don't really use promises for that.  You could just keep track of your own flag or you could test the environment to see if the script is already present.  For example, you could use this function that checks to see if there is a script tag loaded already that ends with a particular filename:

```
function isScriptPresent(fname) {
    var regex = new RegExp(fname + "$");
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
    for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
        if (regex.test(scripts[i].src)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (!isScriptPresent("script.js")) {
    $.getScript("script.js");
}
```

Or, you could make your own getScript function that would first check to see if it was already loaded:

```
$.getScriptIfNotLoaded = function(fname) {
    if (!isScriptPresent(fname)) {
        return $.getScript(fname);
    }
}
```

Then, you could just do:

```
$.getScriptIfNotLoaded("script.js");
```

and, it would never be loaded multiple times in the same page.  This has the advantage that it doesn't matter how the script was first loaded (even if it was in the original HTML) - this will find it if it's already in the page.

---

You could also just keep track of what has been loaded in a map:

```
(function() {
    var loadedScripts = {};

    $.loadScriptOnce = function(fname) {
        if (!loadedScripts[fname]) {
            loadedScripts[fname] = true;
            return $.getScript(fname);
        }
    };
})();

$.loadScriptOnce("scripts.js");
```